# Sencha store and model set up for use with Json

Tags: json, listview, sencha-touch

I've got a Json file......

```
 [
    {   
        "Title":"Package1", 
        "id":"1", 
        "POI":[
            {
                "Title":"POI1", 
                "LayerID":"1", 
            },  
            {
                "Title":"POI2", 
                "LayerID":"1", 
            }
},
 {   
        "Title":"Package2", 
        "id":"2", 
        "POI":[
            {
                "Title":"POI3", 
                "LayerID":"2", 
            },  
            {
                "Title":"POI4", 
                "LayerID":"2", 
            }
}
 ]
```

populating a store.....

```
 Ext.define('Murmuration.store.MyPackages', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
xtype: 'myPackages',

config: {
    model: 'Murmuration.model.PackagesModel',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : 'data/store.json',

    reader: {
        type: 'json'

    }
    },
    autoLoad: true

     }
 });
```

with a model......

```
 Ext.define('Murmuration.model.PackagesModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
xtype: 'packagesModel',
config: {
    fields: [
    {name: 'Title', type: 'string'},
    {name: 'id', type: 'int'}
    ]
     }

 });
```

for said list......

```
 Ext.define('Murmuration.view.homeList', {
extend: 'Ext.List',
xtype: 'homeList',
fulscreen: true,
config: {
    title:'Murmuration',
    itemTpl: '<div>{Title}</div>',
    store:'MyPackages',
fulscreen: true,

     }
 });
```

The list Items are successfully being populated with 'Package1' and 'Package2'. But for the life of me I can't successfully change the code to populate the list with the POI titles for the fist package........'POI1' and 'POI2'. How would I go about successfully implementing the following? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The json you've given is nested so things little different here. First thing is, you need to specify a `rootProperty` in your `reader`. So you define a root element in your json and that element will be set to `rootProperty`.

Next part is, you have `POI` as array of objects. So you'd need a separate model for POI. 
Model for POI can be defined -

```
Ext.define('Murmuration.model.POIModel',{
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
            {name: 'Title', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'LayerID', type: 'int'}
        ],
        belongsTo:'Murmuration.model.PackagesModel'
    }

});
```

After a close look, you'll notice  there's one extra config `belongsTo`. This represents many to one association with your `PackageModel` since there are many POI in each package.

After doing this, you'd need to change you `PackageModel` also to -

```
Ext.define('Murmuration.model.PackagesModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
          {name: 'Title', type: 'string'},
          {name: 'id', type: 'int'}
        ]
    },
    hasMany:{
        associationKey:'POI',
        model:'Murmuration.model.POIModel',
        name:'POI'
    }    
 });
```

here, `hasMany` represents that this model is having multiple model instances of POI model. `associationKey` is the key `POI` from you json and `model` gives the model instance of POI model.

After doing that you'd need to change your reader in store to -

```
Ext.define('Murmuration.store.MyPackages', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',       
config: {
    model: 'Murmuration.model.PackagesModel',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : 'data/store.json',

    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        rootProperty:'items'
    }
    },
    autoLoad: true

     }
 });
```

`rootProperty` should be set to root of you json. I assumed it could be `items` here.

Finally in you view  you can have template set up like this -

```
itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate(['<div>Package Title => {Title}'+
            '<tpl for="POI"><h6>POI title => {Title}</h6><h6>POI layer => {LayerID}</h6></tpl></div>'
        ]),
```

2 things I found in your code are not correct though -

1. Store and Model can not have a `xtype`.
2. All the `config` options should be inside `config:{}` only.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough post, it really helped me understand stores and models more. Looking back over my question though I see I didn't explain myself correctly. I'm looking to parse the json file so that the list is made up of the 2 POIS items, and not the package items. The same way as if I looped through packages[0].POIS[i].Title to give the two POIS in the list. I know in a nested list, these POIS whould be in the secound menu, but I want them to be in the upper level so that they are not nested. When I implemented your code, it gives the first POIS title in each of the Package items

Comment: After spending some more time understanding your code, I have fixed the problem that was on my side. Many thanks again.