# Store array Data Object in localStorage using sencha touch

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, local-storage, sencha-architect

Using sencha touch, I want to store my array list data in localStorage as shown in image.

[image]

onStore refresh function as shown in image below

[image]

I stored simple data as Like Date, Id, Name in LocalStorage on BookStore refresh function. But could not find the way to store arrayObject directly to localStorage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure i understand your question completely..

If you want store javascript object in local Store, you can do it by converting javascript object into string using `JSON.stringify()` method.

```
var testString = JSON.stringify(testObj); //Converts testObject to Json string.
localStorage.testString = testString; // Stores testString into local storage.
```

You can get testString from local storage and convert it into javascript object by

```
var testObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.testString);
```

---

Or you can use

```
Ext.encode(); // Encodes an Object, Array to String.

Ext.decode(); // Decodes (parses) a JSON string to an object.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can store full object but if you just want to store subjects then you need to create new model. 
define a model for storing subjects or you can store the full object you are getting.

```
Ext.define('Demo.model.Subjects', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
            { name: 'id', type: 'int' },
            { name: 'Subjects', type: 'auto' }
        ]
    }
});
```

define a local store

```
Ext.define('Demo.store.MySubjectLocalStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    config: {
        storeId: 'mySubjectLocalStore',
        model: 'Demo.model.Subjects',
        autoLoad: true,
        clearOnPageLoad: true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'localstorage',
            id: 'demo-mySubjects-local-store'
        }
    }
});
```

to store data in local store

```
var subjectsLocal = Ext.getStore('mySubjectLocalStore');

//loop to get your subjects array from main Object then add each array to localstore 
//loop start
var subjects = //get it from parent object inside loop
var subjectsModel = Ext.create('Demo.model.Subjects', {
    Subjects : subjects,
    id: //use integer so that you can get by this id when you retrive  it
});

subjectsLocal.add(subjectsModel);
//loop End

subjectsLocal.sync();
```

Comment: Actually i create my store and model as reference from this example.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14797465/sencha-store-and-model-set-up-for-use-with-json 

so I have 2 ListViews. In Which One View is connect with BookStore and Second ListView with ProductList Store.

My Ajax Request will be called by BookStore and on it load i set all the data to Product Store.

Now my bookStore Data stored in localstorage perfect but productList Data(SubjectList) could not be saved.